# Validation failed for query for method public abstract

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I hope you all doing  good,

I am getting is some issue that i am not able to find how to fix it 
or what to do to fix it

if i want to make a query it could be  possible but i want to try this way this showing below if is it not possible  to this way please also let me know 
I am using ***JPARepository***

```
public Posts findByIdAndCommonFieldActive(int id, boolean active);
```

***My POST ENTITY CLASS***

```
@Entity
@Table(name="post")
public class Posts implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String content;

    @Embedded
    private CommonField commonField;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="post")
    private List<Comments> comments = new ArrayList<Comments>();

   //getter and setter
}
```

***MY COMMON FIELD CLass***

```
@Embeddable
public class CommonField {

    private boolean isActive;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Date modifiedDate;
    private int createdBy;
    private int modifiedBy;

    public CommonField() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public CommonField(boolean isActive, Date createdDate, Date modifiedDate, int createdBy, int modifiedBy) {
        super();
        this.isActive = isActive;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    /// Getter and Setter

}
```

ERROR I am getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.harkesh.model.Posts com.harkesh.repo.PostRepo.findByIdAndCommonFieldActive(int,boolean)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:566) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
```

But whatever be best way you please let me know
Thanks

Comment: Please provide all code of your JPARepository class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
public Posts findByIdAndCommonFieldActive(int id, boolean active);
```

to

```
public Posts findByIdAndCommonFieldIsActive(int id, boolean isActive);
```

should possibly solve your problem.